# flask-marshmallow define schema to convert simple json to complex orm

Tags: python, json, flask, orm, marshmallow

I have some entities in sqlalchemy. They are `User` and messages which they sent `UserMessage`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    email = Column(String)

class UserMessage(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserMessages'
    date = Column(String)
    message = Column(String)

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.uid'))
    user = relationship('User')
```

Now, I want to create a flask resource which let's applications post information in a way which does not map directly to the way the models are actually defined. For example, something like this:

**Json I want to parse**

```
{
    "date": '12345',
    "user": {
    "email": "test@email.com"
},
    "message": "I'm a message"

}
```

All the examples I see for marshmallow involve converting objects in json which are structured in the same way as the orm object. In this example, you would expect the json to look more like this:

**Json marshmallow wants**

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "messages": {
            "message": "I'm a message"
            },
        "date": "12345"
        }
}
```

Will marshammlow allow me to define a more arbitrary schema which will translate between this json and my internal orm objects? If so, can someone please point me at documentation or an example?

Comment: You can add a `pre-load` method to your marshmallow schema. Modify the json structure in this schema.

Comment: My concern here is that I want to use this as part of an etl process which sends in massive posts. It would be pretty inefficient to modify the json, then go through the json again to build the orm objects.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The `pre_load` method in marshmallow does not modify the json itself, but the Python dict deserialized from the json. It takes place between the JSON -> raw Python phase and the raw Python -> object phase. I wouldn't worry about performance penalty at this stage.